# How to add a sigma 3 ring to a contour plot on ROOT

Tags: c++, root-framework

I currently have a CONT4Z plot, with a peak in the center, how do I add a sigma 1 & 3 ring to this, similar to the image included here:
[contour plot with sigma rings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu6J8.png)

I currently have this which is not working:

```
Double_t maximum = levels->GetMaximum();
double contours[2];
contours[0] = 0.68*maximum;
contours[1] = 0.997*maximum;
int colors[2] = {1,1}; 
levels->SetPalette(2,colors);
levels->SetContour(2,contours);
levels->Draw("cont1");


//  T2K->Draw("CONT4Z");  

THStack* hist = new THStack("stack", "Stacked histograms");
hist->Add(T2K);
hist->Add(levels);
hist->Draw("c3");
```

Comment: You don't need a `THStack` for this, a `TH2D` is enough. Please see the example [ContourList](https://root.cern.ch/doc/v608/ContourList_8C.html) from the root documentation. If you're still having troubles, please post a compete working example.